# Heap Sort in Scala

Tags: scala, heap-sort

Trying to implement Heap Sort in Scala

```
class HeapSort
{
    private def swap(array: Array[Int], lhs: Int, rhs: Int) =
    {
        val tmp = array(lhs);
        array(lhs) = array(rhs);
        array(rhs) = tmp;
    }
    private def getParent(child: Int): Int = (child - 1) / 2;
    private def getChildren(parent: Int): Tuple2[Int, Int] =
    {
        val base = parent * 2;
        return (base + 1, base + 2);
    }
    private def swapLargestValue(array: Array[Int], setRoot: (Int) => Unit, root: Int, left: Int, right: Int): Boolean =
    {
        if (array(root) >= array(left) && array(root) >= array(right)) {
            return true;
        }
        if (array(left) >= array(right)) {
            swap(array, root, left);
            setRoot(left);
        }
        else {
            swap(array, root, right);
            setRoot(right);
        }
        return false;
    }
    private def siftDown(array: Array[Int], begin: Int, end: Int): Unit =
    {
        var root = begin;
        var (left, right) = getChildren(root);
        while(left < end) {
            if (swapLargestValue(array, root = _, root, left, if (right < end) right else left)) {
                return;
            }
            val x = getChildren(root);
            left = x._1;
            right = x._2;
        }
    }
    private def heapify(array: Array[Int], end: Int): Unit =
    {
        if (end == 0) {
            return;
        }
        var start = getParent(end - 1);
        while(start >= 0) {
            siftDown(array, start, end);
            start -= 1;
        }
    }
    def heapSort(array: Array[Int]): Unit =
    {
        if (array.length <= 1) {
            return;
        }
        heapify(array, array.length);
        var end = array.length - 1;
        while(end != 0) {
            swap(array, 0, end);
            siftDown(array, 0, end);
            end -= 1;
        }
    }
}

object HS {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        var data = Array(5,6,7,2,3,4,8,9,1,4,6,2,8,5,4,3);
        var hs   = new HeapSort;
        hs.heapSort(data);
        println(data.deep.mkString(", "))
    }
}
```

Comment: @Heslacher: No. It was supposed to be `siftDown()`. It seems to be the standard name for that operation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34329942/siftup-and-siftdown-operation-in-heap-for-hepifying-an-array

Answer (score 1):

Here is How the algorithm works with my sample code.
Push all elements onto a max heap (in place). Then pop off the root node (i.e, max remaining value on heap) until you've popped all values off the heap. The values leave the heap in reverse sorted order, so as the heap shrinks, we can put popped values to the right end of the same array.

> Sample code

```
object HeapSort {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var mess = Array(3, 9, 8, 13, 2, 5, 4);

    sort(mess)
   // buildHeap(mess, mess.length-1)

    mess.foreach( println )
  }

  def sort(a: Array[Int]): Unit = {
    var m = a.length - 1 
    buildHeap(a, m)
    while (m >= 1) {
      swap(a, 0, m)
      m-=1
      heapify(a, 0, m)
    }
  }

  def buildHeap(a: Array[Int], m: Int): Unit = {
    for (i <- m/2 to 0 by -1) {
      heapify(a, i, m)
    }
  }

  /**Pushes an illegally located element down the heap to restore heap property.*/
  @annotation.tailrec
  def heapify(a: Array[Int], loc: Int, lastLeaf: Int): Unit = {
    val l = left(loc) 
    val r = right(loc)

    var max = loc

    if(l <= lastLeaf && a(l) > a(max)) max = l
    if(r <= lastLeaf && a(r) > a(max)) max = r

    if(max != loc) {
      swap(a, max, loc)
      heapify(a, max, lastLeaf)
    }
  }

  /**Returns position of left child (possibly empty). */
  def left(loc: Int): Int = {
    return 2*loc
  }

  /**Returns position of right child (possibly empty). */
  def right(loc: Int): Int = {
    return 2*loc+1
  }

  def swap(a: Array[Int], i: Int, j:Int): Unit = {
    val staging = a(i)
    a(i) = a(j)
    a(j) = staging
  }
}
```

Comment: You've presented an alternative solution without reviewing the code. On Code Review, all answers should contain a review.

Comment: Consider this: `loc=0;left=1;right=2;`Now think about your definition of `left()` and `right()`. Your code is correct if you assume arrays are indexed from 1.

Comment: Thanks for the code couple of questions. Why do you use recursion instead of a loop in `heapify()`. In my code when getting the children I use a tuple and one call. You use two calls (`left()` and `right()`).  Is there a particular reason you choose to use two functions. Is my code bad practice or OK?

Comment: All your methods are public. I tried to hide members that were not useful to the public scope. Is that bad?